# grep -1 freezes, but it should report the invalid flag

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, grep

`grep -1` gives an error, as it should. But

```
$ touch foo
$ grep -1 foo
```

freezes. It doesn't report the invalid flag. Why is this happening? Is it a bug?

I've tested it on Mac (El Capitan) and Ubuntu (14.04).

Comment: As for "as it should" -- options not specified by POSIX are *unspecified behavior*. There is by definition no specified-correct output/behavior in this scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For modern GNU and MacOS BSD implementations, `grep -1 foo` is reading from stdin, filtering files for lines containing `foo` -- which was interpreted as a pattern, not a filename. This differs from `grep foo` by having the amount of context to print surrounding each match set to a single line, thus being equivalent to `grep -C1 foo`.

---

Reading the source to GNU grep, it explicitly allows numbers as short options:

```
static char const short_options[] =
"0123456789A:B:C:D:EFGHIPTUVX:abcd:e:f:hiLlm:noqRrsuvwxyZz";
```

These are stored in `DEFAULT_CONTEXT`, determining how many lines of context to print surrounding each match, unless overridden with the more explicit `-A` or `-B` (indicating how many lines to print after of before a match). This is the same value set with `-C`.

Thus, in the GNU implementation and in BSD implementations extended to behave similarly to it,

```
grep -C3 foo
```

...and...

```
grep -3 foo
```

...behave identically, printing three lines of context surrounding each match.

---

To demonstrate this behavior:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 3 2 1 foo 1 2 3 | grep -0 foo
foo

$ printf '%s\n' 3 2 1 foo 1 2 3 | grep -1 foo
1
foo
1

$ printf '%s\n' 3 2 1 foo 1 2 3 | grep -2 foo
2
1
foo
2
1
```